# How i can read/write file into usb otg in EDC device?

Tags: java, android

I want to export/import database to usb drive with otg in EDC, i have done it,but first i mush open other apps ( U manger) before.

My question is how i can mount usb drive in my apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question: My question is how i can mount usb drive in my apps?

Answer: Developing an App which can read/write from/to USB-OTG-devices from scratch is not that easy. I did it by using a library like this:

https://github.com/magnusja/libaums

This library is very awesome an reliable and is not that hard to implement. Just test the sample application and you will see.

Comment: No problem, I am glad I could help. Best regards